# Defining global variables in a Python Class

Tags: python, class, global-variables

In a Python class I have the following method

```
def foo(self,arg1, arg2):
        global run
        run = False
```

In the same class, in the constructor I have

```
   while run:
            sleep(0.01)
            self.each_frame()  
            self.server.close()
    run = True
```

Is it ok to fine global vars in a class method this way?

Comment: where is run being defined?  There is probably a cleaner way to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 10):

This is a horrible idea. If you need a variable which is shared between instances, define it in the class. If you need a variable shared between methods define them on the object:

```
class Foo(object):
    this_is_a_class_variable = 0

    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.this_is_an_object_variable = None
```

Comment: Yes. It is horrible... this idea. :)

Answer (score 3):

That way your not defining the `global` var just to the scope of the class. *You are defining it to the global scope of your program which is a very bad idea*.

If you want to share state among your classes you have two ways:

1. If you only want to share state between a single instance, then an instances variable should do fine (eg: `self.run = False`)
2. If you want to share state between all instances of your class then *class variables* are the way to go eg: `self.__class__.run = False` or just in your class' definition: `class A(object): run = False`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! So bad practice to define a global this way
Instead in my constructor should have

```
 self.run =true
 while self.run:
         sleep(0.01)
         self.each_frame()  
         self.server.close()
```

And then in the same class in a method

```
  def foo(self,arg1, arg2):
        self.run = False
```

Correct?

Comment: Also, why do you have two accounts?